# Test classes annotated with import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test; are not getting recognized

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, java-17, spring-starter, junit-vintage

Made these changes as part of java 17 and spring boot 3.0.6 upgrade.

- Used these imports:

  ```
  import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
  import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
  import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
  ```
- And these annotations:

  ```
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
    @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
  ```
- Made changes dependencies in settings.gradle

  ```
  testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
  }
  ```
- Also tried without `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

This the error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPkGR.png)

Comment: Hi there , please share the error message as the plain text format